# Oracle lock to calculate MAX

Tags: oracle, plsql

I need to find a safe and correct way to implement this: I am storing an operation log on the database with a sequential EVENT_ID numeric column. I need to be able to delete the last row at anytime and the value in EVENT_ID cannot skip any numbers therefore I can't use a sequence.
I wrote a PL/SQL function that returns MAX(EVENT_ID)+1

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION NEW_ID
(OP_TYPE       IN LOG_TABLE.OP_TYPE_ID%TYPE,
 APP_ID        IN LOG_TABLE.APPLICATION_ID%TYPE)
 RETURN LOG_TABLE.EVENT_ID%TYPE IS
  MYRES LOG_TABLE.EVENT_ID%TYPE;
BEGIN
  LOCK TABLE LOG_TABLE IN EXCLUSIVE MODE NOWAIT;
  SELECT MAX(LOG_TABLE.EVENT_ID) INTO MYRES
    FROM
      LOG_TABLE
    WHERE
      LOG_TABLE.OP_TYPE_ID = OP_TYPE
     AND
      LOG_TABLE.APPLICATION_ID = APP_ID;
  IF MYRES IS NULL THEN
    MYRES := 1;
  ELSE
    MYRES := MYRES + 1;
  END IF;
  RETURN MYRES;
END NEW_ID;
/
```

However there are multiple clients running and reporting on the same database. This means I could end up with multiple equal EVENT_ID values if two or more clients call the function in the exact same moment.
AFAIK locking a table doesn't prevent it being read from other sessions - is there a way to do it? Using a cursor maybe?

Comment: Not a good thing to do, as this will not scale well, but you could use the DBMS_LOCK package to implement your own lock to prevent multiple access.

Comment: Using a "sequence table" where each client that requests a new number locks a row (`update seq_table set event_id = event_id + 1 returning event_id`)  is probably a better solution. If you combine that with a delete trigger on the base table, this should be OK.

Comment: Just keep in mind. Gapless => will not scale. Logically there is no way how to make "fast" - running in parallel.

Comment: But won't my function actually take care of the problem itself? If the LOCK command fails then the whole function should. Am I right?

Comment: What happens when I remove the last row and somebody adds with a +1 id? then it will be directly broken because the removed row goes out with its number. I don't believe it is possible at all.

Answer (score 0):

It is very rare that there is a real business requirement for a gapless sequence, so I think you should still consider using a sequence. If you do insist that you must have no gaps in the generated ID, it is better to use a separate 1-row table, which you can exclusively lock without preventing reads on `LOG_TABLE`, where you would maintain the next available `EVENT_ID` value.

Comment: Unfortunately customs regulations require this number to be 100% sequential for each row or the shipping agent could be fined.

Comment: OK, so this is one of those rare cases.